# Is FaceTime Audio and Video encrypted?

Tags: iphone, encryption, facetime

Is FaceTime audio and video really encrypted? So that we don’t have to worry about anyone listening to our calls when we call using FaceTime?

Comment: I feel that I have adequately answered your question. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Else, let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 7):

**Absolutely it is!**
On Apple's [Approach to Privacy](https://www.apple.com/nz/privacy/approach-to-privacy/) page, you will find the following statement under the iMessage and FaceTime section:

> **We use end-to-end encryption to protect your iMessage and FaceTime conversations across all your devices.** With watchOS and iOS, your messages are encrypted on your device so that they can’t be accessed without your passcode. We designed iMessage and FaceTime so that there’s **no way for us to decrypt your data when it’s in transit between devices**. You can choose to automatically delete your messages from your device after 30 days or a year or to keep them on your device forever...
>   ...and **we never store the content of FaceTime calls on any servers**.

Let me know if that was helpful or if you have any further questions regarding that statement.

Comment: is there a proof from independent security reasearcher?